# Session Timeout(session.setMaxInactiveInterval) is not working in Google Appengine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, session, jakarta-ee, session-timeout

I tried to set the Session timeout for particular users using `session.setMaxInactiveInterval(30*60)` 30 minutes . But by default it's assigned to 86400 seconds (24 hrs).

Also tried in Web.xml

```
<session-config>
  <session-timeout>30</session-timeout> // Session timeout assigned for all the users
</session-config>
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks `HttpSession.setMaxInactiveInterval()` is not honoured by the AppEngine platform anymore (it worked in the past).

You can however still specify session timeout in the `web.xml`:

```
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>  <!-- 30 min --> 
</session-config>
```

Comment: Yeah It will work If i configured in web.xml like this. but it will set for all the users and I don't want that.