# is session.setMaxInactiveInterval() supported on Google App Engine?

Tags: google-app-engine

Is the session.setMaxInactiveInterval() method supported on Google App Engine?

It allows me to set the value, and session.getMaxInactiveInterval() returns the value I set, however the session seems to live on anyway.

Is this a bug in App Engine?

Comment: Not sure if this would be helpful to you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25803917/session-timeoutsession-setmaxinactiveinterval-is-not-working-in-google-appengi

Comment: I need to set it per user, not for the app as a whole.

Comment: Same for me. I set it to 60 and it is well set to 60 qhen I print it directly. But if in my services I print my httpSession.getMaxInactiveInterval() then it is back to 24h (86400).